# Adding arbitrary number of arguments to subclass?

Tags: python, class, inheritance

```
class Restaurant():
    def __init__(self, restaurant_name, cuisine_type):
    """ initializing name and cuisine attributes"""
        self.name = restaurant_name
        self.c_type = cuisine_type
        self.number_served = 0







class IceCreamStand(Restaurant):
"""represents aspects of a type of restaurant specifically an  IceCreamStand """


    def __init__(self, restaurant_name,cuisine_type,flavors):
        super().__init__(restaurant_name, cuisine_type, 
        flavors)
        self.flavor = flavors


    def display_flavors(self):
        print (flavors)



##ICECREAM
dairy_queen = IceCreamStand('dairy queen' , 'ice cream','vanilla' ,'choclate' )
dairy_queen.display_flavors()
```

In my assignment I am trying to make class called IceCreamStand that inherits from the Restaraunt class. I want to also add an attribute that stores a list of flavors and call on this method. This is what i have attempted so far but i keep getting an error message saying **init** takes 4 provisional arguments but 5 were given?

Comment: `flavors` -> `*flavors`. And don't pass `flavors` to `super().__init__`.

Comment: I was going to answer this, but the answer is really one character, and then explanations. Could you remove the unnecessary parts from your code - especially everything following the exception being thrown is just clutter

Comment: @Rawing upon making those edits i get name flavors isn't defined.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala does that mean remove the code after calling the instance? I'm sorry i've been learning for a short time and have no idea  what an exception is.

Comment: @KingsleyBawuah Sorry, didn't spot the 3rd mistake in your code. `print (flavors)` -> `print (self.flavor)`.

Comment: yeah it is better, but it still has a scroll bar there. The rule for examples on Stack Overflow is ["minimal"](/help/mcve) - it should contain everything needed to reproduce the problem, but no more. `greeting`, `open_or_nah` and so forth are useless for this too as they're never called - just remove them, and if the code still results in the same error then that's your new "minimal example".

Comment: @AnttiHaapala I see what you mean, i will take notice of this from now on not just when asking a question but when troubleshooting as well! Thank you for the tips!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a `*` before `flavors` to get all remaining positional arguments into that list.

---

Actually, I'd recommend that you wouldn't use multiple positional arguments for flavors. Pass a `list` in instead:

```
def __init__(self, restaurant_name, cuisine_type, flavors):
    ...

dairy_queen = IceCreamStand('dairy queen' , 'ice cream', ['vanilla' , 'chocolate'])
```

If you use this pattern, you can add another argument with a default value later, and existing code would work without problems:

```
def __init__(self, restaurant_name, cuisine_type, flavors, organic=False):
    ...
```